# Best way to create an element resembling a fraction?

Tags: html, css, fractions

I have tried many ways, including the following:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: auto; float: left; margin: 2px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td style="text-align: center;padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align: center; padding: 5px;">5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
<span class="fraction">
    <span>5</span>
    <span>3</span>
</span>
<style type="text/css">
.fraction{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.fraction>span{
    display:block;
}
.fraction>span:first-child{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

So I was wondering, is there a better way using less elements? (For example, the first one used `table`, `tbody`, 2 `tr`s & 2 `td`s)

Comment: I think the table-based solution is bad as it needlessly complicates the document flow. Fractions like this are usually used inline, along with some text. It might be a good idea for longer and more complicated formulas, though. Did you know you could use a fraction slash entity character for simple fractions like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tWSZ7/

Comment: yes, so now I am using the `span` method.

Comment: so I wanted to inquiry if I have missed out a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If the layout doesn't have to be perfectly vertical :**

`<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>10</sub>`

which would produce : <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>10</sub>

**If it has to be vertical :**

your solution is one of the best I think.

**If you want to have an easy way to write fractions :**

You could use a Javascript library http://www.mathjax.org/ or http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html for instance.

**If you want to look like Wikipedia :**

use images generated by a TeX distribution :)

Comment: **+1** Didn't know about `&frasl;`

Comment: I'm sorry but it needs to be perfectly vertical

Comment: Well then, there is no other method "simple" in HTML / CSS .

I will edit my answer to give some alternatives but there is nothing else in pure HTML / CSS with the minimum of markup possible.